# Saves Individual Worksheets as Workbooks in destination folder

Tags: vba, excel

This code takes, on average, 6 minutes to fully run with the workbook I am using. The workbook currently has 148 worksheets and will grow consistently with time.

I am curious if there is a way to edit the code from doing the task one worksheet at a time; and, instead complete the task all in one moment. In my mind, the code would run for a much shorter time and then populate all the worksheets as separate workbooks in the file destination at the same time. The worksheets would also not "pop-up" before saving themselves in the destination folder. Much like stopping screen updating and automatic calculations making a world of difference - except that did not work with this code.

```
Sub SaveFilesInFolder()
'
'Macro for saving each worksheet as a workbook in a destination folder
'

'
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each sh In Worksheets
    SheetName = sh.Name
    sh.Copy

        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:="FolderDestination" & SheetName
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With

    Next sh

End Sub
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You declare `wb` but do not use it. Perhaps this provides a clue.

Comment: Just an aside question. Why on earth would anyone think it is a good idea to make a 148sheet workbook?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to [turn off screenupdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-screenupdating-property-excel), [turn off alerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-displayalerts-property-excel) and auto-save and [close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel).

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
```

So, like this -

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitSheetsToBooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Const PATH_TO As String = "C:\TEMP\"
    Const EXCEL_EXTENTION As String = ".xlsx"

    Dim index As Long
    Dim numberOfSheets As Long
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    numberOfSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    For index = 1 To numberOfSheets
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(index)
        targetSheet.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PATH_TO & targetSheet.Name & EXCEL_EXTENTION
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code works exactly how I imagined; however, there is an issue I cannot figure out. The files do not follow the PATH_TO, they instead save to my desktop with the filename "TestSheet1". I have no idea why and I can't see anything in the code that would be causing this.